# JDA - I've written a bot but cannot get it to run

Tags: java, discord-jda

So I've got the code for the bot to work, and answer commands, however I need to call it to actually make it work and I cannot figure how to do that, I've looked on the wiki but being relatively new to Java a lot is confusing.

I have tried doing DiscordBot.jda. and seeing what methods are available but I can't see much - I'll include the code for my whole bot

```java
public class DiscordBot extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static JDA jda;

    public void initialize() {
        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
        builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        builder.setToken("");
        builder.addEventListeners(this);
        try {
            jda = builder.build();
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final String PREFIX = "::";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        String message = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();

        String[] command = message.split("-");

        if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "players")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("There are currently " + World.getPlayers().size() + " players online.")
                    .queue();

            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Naxos!");
            embed.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            embed.setDescription("");
            embed.addField("There are currently " + World.getPlayers().size() + " online!", "", false);
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
        }

        if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "vote")) {



            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Naxos Voting!");
            embed.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            embed.setDescription("");
            embed.addField("Do ::vote in-game", "", false);
            embed.addField("Or head too http://.net/vote", "", false);
            embed.addField("Vote on all the sites", "", false);
            embed.addField("Do ::rewards 1 all", "", false);
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();

        }

        if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "store")) {

            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Naxos Voting!");
            embed.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            embed.setDescription("");
            embed.addField("Do ::donate in-game", "", false);
            embed.addField("Or head too http://.net/store", "", false);
            embed.addField("Purchase whatever you would like", "", false);
            embed.addField("Do ::claim in-game!", "", false);
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();

        }

        if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "website")) {
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Naxos Website");
            embed.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            embed.setDescription("");
            embed.addField(event.getMember().getAsMention() + " http://.net", "", false);
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();

        }

        if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "discordcommands")) {
            System.out.println("Command executed");
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("Naxos commands");
            embed.setColor(Color.RED);
            embed.setDescription("");
            embed.addField("::store", "", false);
            embed.addField("::players", "", false);
            embed.addField("::vote", "", false);
            embed.addField("::website", "", false);

            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();

        }

    }

}
```

I need to call the bot in my main method, I believe to make it work, I just wouldn't know how to make this work by calling it from a different method.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "not working" isnt a problem description that works too good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a main method to actually start the application, add this to your class to make it start your bot.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DiscordBot().initialize();
}
```